# Create new Dataframe column based on existing Dataframes in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

There are two DF's , I need to populate a new column in `DF1` say `Flag` on below conditions.

```
DF1
    +------+-------------------+
    ||AMOUNT|Brand             | 
    +------+-------------------+
    | 47.88|          Parle    |
    | 40.92|          Parle    |
    | 83.82|          Parle    |
    |106.58|          Parle    |
    | 90.51|          Flipkart |
    | 11.48|          Flipkart |
    | 18.47|          Flipkart |
    | 40.92|          Flipkart |
    |  30.0|          Flipkart |
    +------+-------------------+


DF2

+--------------------+-------+----------+
|       Brand        |   P1  |   P2     |
+--------------------+-------+----------+
|               Parle| 37.00 |  100.15  |
|            Flipkart|  10.0 |  30.0    |
+--------------------+-------+----------+
```

if the amount of say Brand `Parle` in `DF1` is less than  P1 value `(Amount < P1)` in `DF2` for the brand "`Parle`", then flag will be `low`, if   `P1 >= amount <= P2` than flag will be `mid` and if `Amount > P2` then `high`,
Similarly for other merchants too.

the DF1 is having very huge data and DF2 is very small.

```
expected output

+------+-------------------+----------------+
||AMOUNT|Brand             |        Flag    |
+------+-------------------+----------------+
| 47.88|          Parle    |   mid          |
| 40.92|          Parle    |   mid          |
| 83.82|          Parle    |   mid          |
|106.58|          Parle    |   high         |
| 90.51|          Flipkart |   high         |
| 11.48|          Flipkart |   mid          |
| 18.47|          Flipkart |   mid          |
| 40.92|          Flipkart |   high         |
|  30.0|          Flipkart |   mid          |
+------+-------------------+----------------
```

I know that I can do a join and get the results, but how should i frame to logic in spark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple `left` join and nested `when` inbuilt functions should get your desired result as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df1.join(df2, Seq("Brand"), "left")
  .withColumn("Flag", when(col("AMOUNT") < col("P1"), "low").otherwise(
    when(col("AMOUNT") >= col("P1") && col("AMOUNT") <= col("P2"), "mid").otherwise(
      when(col("AMOUNT") > col("P2"), "high").otherwise("unknown"))))
    .select("AMOUNT", "Brand", "Flag")
  .show(false)
```

which should give you

```
+------+--------+----+
|AMOUNT|Brand   |Flag|
+------+--------+----+
|47.88 |Parle   |mid |
|40.92 |Parle   |mid |
|83.82 |Parle   |mid |
|106.58|Parle   |high|
|90.51 |Flipkart|high|
|11.48 |Flipkart|mid |
|18.47 |Flipkart|mid |
|40.92 |Flipkart|high|
|30.0  |Flipkart|mid |
+------+--------+----+
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: Thanks, I tried to use Broadcast join but its resulting in error.

`val df2 = broadcast(DF2.as("df2"))`
 
` df1.join(broadcast(df2), Seq("Brand"), "left")
    .withColumn("Flag", when(col("AMOUNT") < col("P1"), "low").otherwise(
      when(col("AMOUNT") >= col("P1") && col("AMOUNT") <= col("P2"), "mid").otherwise(
        when(col("AMOUNT") > col("P2"), "high").otherwise("unknown"))))
    .select("AMOUNT", "Brand", "Flag")
    .show(false)`

Comment: The solution should work but in case you want to use broadcast then use it for small dataframe and use it as `import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
    df1.join(broadcast(df2), Seq("Brand"), "left")
      .withColumn("Flag", when(col("AMOUNT") < col("P1"), "low").otherwise(
        when(col("AMOUNT") >= col("P1") && col("AMOUNT") <= col("P2"), "mid").otherwise(
          when(col("AMOUNT") > col("P2"), "high").otherwise("unknown"))))
        .select("AMOUNT", "Brand", "Flag")
      .show(false)`

Comment: Your solution is working. but i am trying to do a broadcast join

Comment: Yeah, even the broadcast is working. I had some syntax error earlier in the code

Comment: great to hear that @Sanjay

Answer (score 0):

I think with udf is also doable.

```
val df3 = df1.join(df2, Seq("Brand"), "left")
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val mapper = udf((amount: Double, p1: Double, p2: Double) => if (amount < p1) "low" else if (amount > p2) "high" else "mid")
df3.withColumn("Flag", mapper(df3("AMOUNT"), df3("P1"), df3("P2")))
    .select("AMOUNT", "Brand", "Flag")
    .show(false)
```

Comment: Thanks. I have a question here, Can we like specify _ in select, like select all columns, instead of specifying individual cols?

Comment: You can skip .select() at all if specific columns selection not needed.

Comment: Thanks, I din't knew that :)